# How to use source control for a team services release definition to encourage peer review?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm delegating another person to make changes to a release definition and I'd love to be able to review their changes before it gets saved.

Using source control - Git or TFVC - we could review these changes before they go live.

Before I add a request on [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/category/145269-release-management), is there a preferred method for going about this?  Is my google-foo not turning up an answer?

I've always found it peculiar that the release and build definitions only appear to be saved in the cloud and not to a repository of your choosing.  We can see the json files and compare them in the browser but only after they have been saved.  And I can't link them to a work item to provide some history of `Who, how and why did the build/release definition get to look like this?` other than making work item references in the comment field when a build or release is saved.  Previously the old TFSBuild.proj or newer XAML build files were at least in source control.

Does anyone at Microsoft have some insight on this?  Are we using it incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Using a source control is done in order to save versions and be able to work on different branches, sounds like you're looking for tools like: https://www.reviewboard.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'd love for them to add support for "build and release definitions as code", but you can fudge the process with REST APIs.

Store the release definitions in source control as JSON and create a CI process on commit that uses the TFS REST API to update/import the release definition. An existing release definition can be exported as JSON to provide a baseline -- there are plenty of extensions on the marketplace to handle this, or you can export it via the REST API. At that point, you can lock people out of being able to directly modify the release definitions, limiting permissions to the service account.

If people still want to work against a GUI for the release definitions (which is reasonable), you can give them access to a sandbox team project where they have rights to create/modify release definitions. They can always export it when they're done tweaking.

Comment: I saw the REST API and was thinking along these seem lines, but was hoping not to burn unbillable time on side-quests like this.  Welp, here's to hoping something out-of-the-box is on the way.

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the feature to review changes of release definition. The workaround that Daniel provided is good.

I submit a user voice here: [Review changes of release definition](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18146761-review-changes-of-release-definition)